# Problem with permission installing node-sass

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am trying to install node-sass in a create react app. I tried running:

```
sudo npm install node-sass --save
```

And I get the following error:

```
    Unable to save binary /Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
at sync (/Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
at Function.sync (/Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
at checkAndDownloadBinary (/Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'mkdir',
path: '/Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }
```

This is followed by post install action:

```
node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall /Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/node-sass
```

This runs a lot more code, but for the sake of being concise I am not including it as the error is likely with the 'Error: EACCES: permission denied'

What is the permission that is being denied here and how can I approve it?

**EDIT:**

When I try running the same command (i.e. without `sudo`):

```
npm install node-sass --save
```

I get the following warning:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/jest-cli
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/node-pre-gyp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/tar
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/username/Desktop/code/advocado/node_modules/regexpu-core
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed.'
```

Comment: Yes, it says that I do not have proper permissions to write in the folder when I do not use sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Give yourself permission to edit this directory

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```